# How can I link to a slide from an linked table in google slides?

Tags: google-sheets, google-slides

I have a google slide presentation where I have linked a table coming from a google sheet file

I want some of the cell in the table to link some specific slides in my presentation

I have the ID of the slide I want to link so I created the link in the sheet but when I embed the cells into the slide the link does not work.

Here a screenshot, hope it helps.

My goal is to to make a presentation with many slides each showing a pivot table. The pivot has links to other slides where detailed data about that specific record are shown

[image: Screenshot to my presentation]

Comment: Can you provide the sample URL of your hyperlink to the specific slide?

Comment: sorry if maybe i don't understand your question but the URL is the one you see in the image. Is a relative link starting with #

Comment: From `the URL is the one you see in the image. Is a relative link starting with #`, if you are directly using `#slide=id.{slideId}`, when you modify the URL to `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/{presentationId}/edit#slide=id.{slideId}`, is that your expected result? But, I'm not sure whether my understanding of your reply is correct. I apologize for this.

Comment: when I use the full link instead of the relative link I get redirected to google slide in edit mode and not in slideshow mode. Also when I convert the slideshow into PDF the link again send me to a browser page instead of going to the correct page in acrobat reader. Tha'ts why I need relative link

Answer (score 1):

You can directly link to a slide in presenter mode by using a full link in the source table in Sheets of the form: `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/{presentationId}/present#slide=id.{slideId}`

N.B. when you click on the link in your presentation, it opens the linked slide in a new browser tab (rather than the current tab used for the presentation). I'm not sure if this is a problem for your intended use-case or not (in Chrome you should be able to use Ctrl+W to close the 'linked' tab and step back to the main slide deck tab even if you're in full screen mode?)

Comment: thank you. It works and it's a big step toward what I intend to do. If I could find a way to open the link in the same tab it would be great. I would also be great if it worked even when converted to PDF. But I guess I need relative links for that

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I'm going to award it with the bounty because it's an improvement and does help me. I'm not still going to accept it because it does not fully resolve my problem